# Sequence numbering

Tags: vba

I have an Access table with values like `XX-033inRF6005`.
This unique string will need a sequence number concatenated to it like `XX-033inRF6005001`.

The sequence number should:

- Name the first two records with `XX-033inRF6005001`.
- Third record as `XX-033inRF6005002`
- Fourth as `XX-033inRF6005002`
- Fifth as `XX-033inRF6005003`
- Sixth as `XX-033inRF6005003`

  etc..

how do I achieve this in VBA. any clue pls?

Comment: How do you decide the record order?

Comment: Record order can be any. Just based on the uniqueness, it need to add the sequence number.

Comment: I can't see any uniqueness in the example you've given - all six records are `XX-033inRF6005`.  Does that value change at all - you've put _values like_ so I guess it does?  Does the number sequence start again if the main value changes?

Comment: Hi with the same string "XX-033inRF6005" the report has at least 1000 entries. So need to sequence it and identify for my programming

Answer (score 0):

dont know much about access, but the basics for this should be

```
for i = 2 to 2 * LastSequencenumber
    x(i) = "XX-033inRF6005" & format(int(i/2),"000")
next i
```

Of course you can read in somehow the values from your table, but i dont know how to do it in access

Comment: how does system knows "Last sequence number". pls advice

Comment: thats up to your needs, if `XX-033inRF6005012` is the last then it's 12. I just showed how to concatenate the number in the wanted format. You need to figure out how far it should count and put it in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what *sequence it and identify for my programming* means so here's a quick and dirty way to add the number sequence to the records in your table.
Every two records that meet the criteria have the current `cntr` value added to it as a three digit number.

This will only deal with `XX-033inRF6005` as you haven't said what you want done with other numbers - restart the number, ignore them, continue as if they're the same number.

The name of your table and field will need updating in the code below.

```
Public Sub AddNumbering()

    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim cntr As Long

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "SELECT Field_1 FROM Table1 WHERE Field_1 = 'XX-033inRF6005'")

    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset

    cntr = 1

    With rst
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            .MoveFirst
            Do While Not .EOF
                .Edit
                'Format(cntr,"000") ensures the number is 3 digits long - 001, 002, etc.
                !Field_1 = !Field_1 & Format(cntr, "000")
                .Update
                .MoveNext

                If Not .EOF Then
                    .Edit
                    !Field_1 = !Field_1 & Format(cntr, "000")
                    .Update
                    .MoveNext
                End If

                cntr = cntr + 1
            Loop
        End If

        .Close
        qdf.Close
    End With

    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing

End Sub
```